# What does Shadowform do to other classes' Hero powers?

Tags: hearthstone

When Shadowform is cast as a Priest, the Hero Ability changes its name from *"Lesser Heal"* to *"Mind Spike"* and does 2 damage or *"Mind Shatter"* doing 3 damage (depending on how often you cast Shadowform) instead of healing for 2. The icon also changes from a hand held upwards with dominant yellow and orange tones into a hand held towards the player with a bright spot in the center and dominant purple and black tones.

What happens to your Hero Power if you cast Shadowform **as a non-Priest**? According to the card's text, it also deals 2/3 damage, without anything else specified. So does its name and icon change to the same as the Priest's variant or is there a different name and icon for each class?

Oh, and before anyone asks: *Lorewalker Cho*.

Comment: sounds like a fun experiment to try and set up.  Too bad I don't have a lorewalker cho.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The name and icon remain the same. A warrior for example, loses his Armor Up! and gains Mind Spike just as a priest would. The same applies (if I recall correctly) to an aditional Shadowform. You gain the Mind Shatter ability with the corresponding icon. Just as it says on the card.

Edit: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLulFzS5QSc) shows an example of a Warlock gaining Mind Spike by using Lorewalker Cho.

Comment: Looks right to me. Someone will surely point it out if it changed for some reason. Thanks!